# How many ways are there to place 10 distinct people within 3 distinct rooms with exactly 5 people in the first room and 2 people in the second room?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion

So I was given this question. How many ways are there to place $10$ distinct people within $3$ distinct rooms with exactly $5$ people in the first room and $2$ people in the second room?

I have worked on a similar problem but it did not ask about the $5$ people in the first room and $2$ in the other, So that part is what is really throwing me off.

I started this off saying There are $3^{10}$ unique ways to assign $10$ distinct people in three rooms of which $3^{10} - 3 \cdot 2^{10} + 5$

After this I'm completely confused.

Comment: Hint: First **choose** who goes into Room 1.  (It is marginally easier to first choose who goes into Room 2.)

Comment: @AndréNicolas Uhm So you would just kind of break it off like saying the first 5 people go into the first room?

Comment: The people who go into the first room can be chosen in $\binom{10}{5}$ ways. For *each* of these ways, the people who go into the second room csn be chosen in $\binom{5}{2}$ ways. So the total number of ways is $\binom{10}{5}\binom{5}{2}$. You probably would be expected to find a numerical solution.

Comment: @AndréNicolas so the answer provided by miniparser would be correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

i believe the answer is ${10\choose 5}{5\choose 2}{3\choose 3}$ which can also be expressed as ${10\choose {5,2,3}}$.

$3^{10}$ would be if there were no rules as to how many go in each room

Comment: I'm pretty confident you would use the inclusion exclusion principle and counting. Can you explain how you got that answer?

Comment: first choose any 5, then any 2 of remaining.